# Redshift indicator usage

Tags: 12.04, indicator

I use this command when starting the computer: 
`gtk-redshift-l 36.47: -6.20 6400:4400-g 0.8-m-v vidmode`

The first question is whether I've used this command correctly, and the second is whether the program needs to be running both at night and during the day.  I think so because of day and night changes -- please correct me if I'm wrong.

*(Without translation:
Dos preguntitas sobre este programita tan útil. Yo tengo este comando al iniciar ordenador: gtk-redshift -l 36.47:-6.20 6400:4400 -g 0.8 -m vidmode -v
La 1era pregunta es sobre si este comando esta bien utilizado y la 2ª es saber si el programa siempre tiene que estar activo, tanto en la noche como en el día. Yo creo que sí porque según el día y la noche va cambiando -- corriganme si me equivoco.)*

Comment: Cierra el tema, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command seems to correct except for some space indents. All the parameters are passed correctly. Only parameters that is found missing is the time (-t) parameter. The correct command for the same will be:

```
redshift -l 36.47:-6.20 -t 6400:4400 -g 0.8 -m vidmode -v
```

Comment: make it the answer if you found it as the right command as it may help others and also I +1 to you for letting me experience with such a nice application.